# dismissViewControllerAnimated Crashes EXC

Tags: ios, swift, model-view-controller, uiviewcontroller, crash

I've been trying to present and dismiss a view controller programmatically and I keep running into EXC issues.

What is the proper way to present and dismiss a view controller other than using:

```
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("Popup") as UIViewController

    self.presentViewController(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

and self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)

?

So far the app crashes when i run the function: **dismissViewControllerAnimated**

Please help, thanks!

Comment: is it got called in UI thread?

Comment: are you dismissing the root view controller?

Comment: @HoaParis Not really sure, I didn't think dispatch was needed for this kinda of UI Updating

Comment: @Louis Tur, I'm not sure although, If i dismiss the root view controller i don't know if I can programmatically call it back when I dismiss the foreground viewController.

Comment: Can you show your crash log?

Comment: 2015-02-26 21:16:06.384 Tour[11759:607] *** -[App.ViewController2 release]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x7e16c180
(lldb)

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, I had a NSNotification listener in the ViewController which caused the crash.

What I did was take it out and re-did the ViewController to populate the View Controller via a method rather than use a method linked to a NSNotification Listener.